# Binding a terminal command to a set of keys for Kubuntu 15.10

Tags: sound, kubuntu, music

I have just installed cmus and to run it I need to go into terminal and enter the command "cmus". Is there any way I can bind this to a set of keys?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a shortcut for cmus via Terminator while running Kubuntu first follow this path:

```
KMenu > System Settings > Shortcuts & Gestures > Custom Shortcuts
```

From here you can create the shortcut by drilling through this path:

```
Edit > New > Global Shortcut > Command/URL
```

Now follow these steps:

1. Where it says 'New Action' type in 'Open Cmus' (without the apostrophes)
2. Go to 'Trigger > Shortcut' and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> (or other keys)
3. Go to 'Action' and type in: `terminator -e cmus`
4. Press 'Apply'

This works beautifully on my system:

[image]

KDE will obligingly tell you if there is any conflict with the key combination you have selected versus any existing shortcuts...

Comment: this doesn't work as i am on kubuntu. I have terminator installed and tried replacing gnome-terminal with terminator but it does not work. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ooops! My apologies for not reading the question properly. I have rewritten my answer completely to address Kubuntu and Terminator running cmus....